# Both render function have same code, but only one can work,why?

Tags: javascript, html, class

I want to use two `render` functions to render two class.

```js
class SidebarView {
  constructor(model, root) {
    this.root = root;
    this.model = model;
    model.addObserver(x => this.update(x));
  }

  render() {
    this.root.innerHTML = `<span>${this.model.getNumberOfGuests()}</span>`;
  }

  update(whatHappened) {
    this.root.secondElementChild.textContent = whatHappened.guests;
  }
}
```

```js
class SummaryView {
  constructor(model, root) {
    this.root = root;
    this.model = model;
    model.addObserver(x => this.update(x));
  }

  render() {
    this.root.innerHTML = `Dinner for <span>${this.model.getNumberOfGuests()}</span> people`;
  }

  update(whatHappened) {
    this.root.firstElementChild.textContent = whatHappened.guests;
  }
}
```

```js
class DinnerModel {
  constructor() {
    this.numberOfGuests = 2;
    this.subscribers = [];
  }
  setNumberOfGuests(x) {
    this.numberOfGuests = x;
    this.notifyObservers({
      guests: x
    });
    return x
    // TODO TW1.1
  }
  getNumberOfGuests() {
    return this.numberOfGuests // TODO TW1.1
  }

  addObserver(callback) {
    this.subscribers.push(callback);
    console.log(this.subscribers)
  }
  notifyObservers(whatHappened) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.subscribers.length; i++) {
      return this.subscribers[i](whatHappened)
    }
  }
}

const model = new DinnerModel();
new SummaryView(model, document.body.querySelector("#summary")).render();
new SidebarView(model, document.body.querySelector("#sidebar")).render();

function onModelChange(payload) {
  document.body.textContent = payload.guests;
}

model.addObserver(onModelChange);
```

These codes are almost the same but only Summary can work well ,I don't know why.

I can see the number 2 in the browser but for sidebar, I can't change the number through console.
Only summary can change the number through the console.

Thanks in advance.As I am a starter of Javascript, it could be a stupid question.

Comment: `notifyObservers()` only executes the first subscriber, because it uses `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `notifyObservers()` returns after notifying the first subscriber. You shouldn't have `return` in the loop, since that ends the function immediately, and never continues with the other subscribers.

Just call the subscribers without returning.

```
  notifyObservers(whatHappened) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.subscribers.length; i++) {
      this.subscribers[i](whatHappened)
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for answering, But when I delete `return`  the browser gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined.

Comment: `secondElementChild` is not a standard DOM property. What is `this.root.secondElementChild` supposed to be?